# MATLAB vs. FIJI statistical region merging algorithm speed: why is FIJI faster?

Tags: java, image, performance, matlab, imagej

I have assembled an algorithm in MATLAB and as part of that am using statistical region merging. I have versions of this in MATLAB and Fiji (ImageJ), both included below. Both versions are based on the Nock and Nielson model and seem similar (although I'm not too familiar with Java/Fiji). When I run this on a 1500x500 2d grayscale image in MATLAB it takes around 3 seconds to process versus less than a second in Fiji. I've tried trimming down the MATLAB code as much as I can but am still running into this speed issue. What's causing this timing difference? Thanks

[MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25619-image-segmentation-using-statistical-region-merging):

```
    % Statistical Region Merging
%
% Nock, Richard and Nielsen, Frank 2004. Statistical Region Merging. IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell. 26, 11 (Nov. 2004), 1452-1458.
% DOI= http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2004.110

%Segmentation parameter Q; Q small few segments, Q large may segments

function [maps,images]=srm3(image,Qlevels)

% Smoothing the image, comment this line if you work on clean or synthetic images
h=fspecial('gaussian',[3 3],1);
image=imfilter(image,h,'symmetric');

smallest_region_allowed=10;

size_image=size(image);
n_pixels=size_image(1)*size_image(2);

% Compute image gradient
[Ix,Iy]=srm_imgGrad(image(:,:,:));
Ix=max(abs(Ix),[],3);
Iy=max(abs(Iy),[],3);
normgradient=sqrt(Ix.^2+Iy.^2);

Ix(:,end)=[];
Iy(end,:)=[];

[~,index]=sort(abs([Iy(:);Ix(:)]));

n_levels=numel(Qlevels);
maps=cell(n_levels,1);
images=cell(n_levels,1);
im_final=zeros(size_image);
Q=256;
map=reshape(1:n_pixels,size_image(1:2));
% gaps=zeros(size(map)); % For future release
treerank=zeros(size_image(1:2));

size_segments=ones(size_image(1:2));
image_seg=image;

%Building pairs
n_pairs=numel(index);
idx2=reshape(map(:,1:end-1),[],1);
idx1=reshape(map(1:end-1,:),[],1);

pairs1=[ idx1;idx2 ];
pairs2=[ idx1+1;idx2+size_image(1) ];


    for i=1:n_pairs
        C1=pairs1(index(i));
        C2=pairs2(index(i));

        %Union-Find structure, here are the finds, average complexity O(1)
        while (map(C1)~=C1 ); C1=map(C1); end
        while (map(C2)~=C2 ); C2=map(C2); end

        % Compute the predicate, region merging test
        g=256;
        logdelta=2*log(6*n_pixels);

        dR=(image_seg(C1)-image_seg(C2))^2;

        logreg1 = min(g,size_segments(C1))*log(1.0+size_segments(C1));
        logreg2 = min(g,size_segments(C2))*log(1.0+size_segments(C2));

        dev1=((g*g)/(2.0*Q*size_segments(C1)))*(logreg1 + logdelta);
        dev2=((g*g)/(2.0*Q*size_segments(C2)))*(logreg2 + logdelta);

        dev=dev1+dev2;

        predicat=( (dR<dev) ); 

        if (((C1~=C2)&&predicat) ||  xor(size_segments(C1)<=smallest_region_allowed, size_segments(C2)<=smallest_region_allowed))
            % Find the new root for both regions
            if treerank(C1) > treerank(C2)
                map(C2) = C1; reg=C1;
            elseif treerank(C1) < treerank(C2)
                map(C1) = C2; reg=C2;
            elseif C1 ~= C2
                map(C2) = C1; reg=C1;
                treerank(C1) = treerank(C1) + 1;
            end

            if C1~=C2
                % Merge region
                nreg=size_segments(C1)+size_segments(C2);
                size_segments(C1);
                size_segments(C2);
                image_seg(reg)=(size_segments(C1)*image_seg(C1)+size_segments(C2)*image_seg(C2))/nreg;
                size_segments(reg)=nreg;
            end
        end
    end

    while 1
        map_ = map(map) ;
        if isequal(map_,map) ; break ; end
        map = map_ ;
    end

    im_final(:,:,1)=image_seg(map+(1-1)*n_pixels);
    images{1}=im_final;
```

[Fiji](https://github.com/fiji/Statistical_Region_Merging/blob/master/src/main/java/SRM_.java):

```
 * Statistical Region Merging.
 * %%
 * Copyright (C) 2009 - 2013 Johannes Schindelin.
 * %%
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 * The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are
 * those of the authors and should not be interpreted as representing official
 * policies, either expressed or implied, of any organization.
 * #L%
 */


import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.ImageStack;
import ij.gui.GenericDialog;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.process.ByteProcessor;
import ij.process.FloatProcessor;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;
import ij.process.ShortProcessor;

import java.util.Arrays;

/*
 * The Statistical Region Merging algorithm is described in
 *
 * R. Nock, F. Nielsen: Statistical Region Merging.
 * IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell. 26(11): 1452-1458 (2004)
 */

public class SRM_ implements PlugInFilter {
    ImagePlus image;

    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus image) {
        this.image = image;
        return DOES_8G | NO_CHANGES;
    }

    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        boolean isStack = image.getStackSize() > 1;

        GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog("SRM");
        gd.addNumericField("Q", Q, 2);
        gd.addCheckbox("showAverages", true);
        if (isStack)
            gd.addCheckbox("3d", true);
        gd.showDialog();

        if (gd.wasCanceled())
            return;

        Q = (float)gd.getNextNumber();
        boolean showAverages = gd.getNextBoolean();
        boolean do3D = isStack ? gd.getNextBoolean() : false;
        if (do3D)
            srm3D(showAverages).show();
        else
            srm2D(ip, showAverages).show();
    }

    final float g = 256; // number of different intensity values
    protected float Q = 25; //25; // complexity of the assumed distributions
    protected float delta;

    /*
     * The predicate: is the difference of the averages of the two
     * regions R and R' smaller than
     *
     * g sqrt(1/2Q (1/|R| + 1/|R'|) ln 2/delta)
     *
     * Instead of calculating the square root all the time, we calculate
     * the factor g^2 / 2Q ln 2/delta, and compare
     *
     * (<R> - <R'>)^2 < factor (1/|R| + 1/|R'|)
     *
     * instead.
     */
    protected float factor, logDelta;

    /*
     * For performance reasons, these are held in w * h arrays
     */
    float[] average;
    int[] count;
    int[] regionIndex; // if < 0, it is -1 - actual_regionIndex

    /*
     * The statistical region merging wants to merge regions in a specific
     * order: for all neighboring pixel pairs, in ascending order of
     * intensity differences.
     *
     * In that order, it is tested if the regions these two pixels belong
     * to (by construction, the regions must be distinct) should be merged.
     *
     * For efficiency, we do it by bucket sorting, because there are only
     * g + 1 possible differences.
     *
     * After sorting, for each difference the pixel pair with the largest
     * index is stored in neighborBuckets[difference], and every
     * nextNeighbor[index] points to the pixel pair with the same
     * difference and the next smaller index (or -1 if there is none).
     *
     * The pixel pairs are identified by
     *
     *     2 * (x + (w - 1) * y) + direction
     *
     * where direction = 0 means "right neighbor", and direction = 1 means
     * " lower neighbor".  (We do not need "left" or "up", as the order
     * within the pair is not important.)
     *
     * In n dimensions, it must be n * pixel_count, and "direction"
     * specifies the Cartesian unit vector (axis) determining the neighbor.
     */
    int[] nextNeighbor, neighborBucket;

    protected ImagePlus srm3D(boolean showAverages) {
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        int d = image.getStackSize();

        delta = 1f / (6 * w * h * d);
        /*
         * This would be the non-relaxed formula:
         *
         * factor = g * g / 2 / Q * (float)Math.log(2 / delta);
         *
         * The paper claims that this is more prone to oversegmenting.
         */
        factor = g * g / 2 / Q;
        logDelta = 2f * (float)Math.log(6 * w * h * d);

        IJ.showStatus("Initializing regions");
        initializeRegions3D(w, h, d);
        IJ.showStatus("Initializing neighbors");
        initializeNeighbors3D(w, h, d);
        IJ.showStatus("Merging neighbors");
        mergeAllNeighbors3D(w, h);
        IJ.showStatus("Making stack");

        ImageStack stack = new ImageStack(w, h);
        if (showAverages)
            for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
                int off = k * w * h;
                float[] p = new float[w * h];
                for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
                    p[i] = average[getRegionIndex(i + off)];
                stack.addSlice(null, new FloatProcessor(w, h,
                            p, null));
            }
        else {
            int regionCount = consolidateRegions();

            if (regionCount > 1<<16)
                IJ.showMessage("Found " + regionCount
                    + " regions, which does not fit"
                    + " in 16-bit.");

            for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
                ImageProcessor ip;

                int off = k * w * h;

                if (regionCount > 1<<8) {
                    short[] p = new short[w * h];
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
                        p[i] = (short)regionIndex[i
                            + off];
                    ip = new ShortProcessor(w, h, p, null);
                }
                else {
                    byte[] p = new byte[w * h];
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
                        p[i] = (byte)regionIndex[i
                            + off];
                    ip = new ByteProcessor(w, h, p, null);
                }
                stack.addSlice(null, ip);
            }
        }

        IJ.showStatus("");
        String title = image.getTitle() + " (SRM3D Q=" + Q + ")";
        return new ImagePlus(title, stack);
    }

    protected ImagePlus srm2D(ImageProcessor ip, boolean showAverages) {
        int w = ip.getWidth(), h = ip.getHeight();

        delta = 1f / (6 * w * h);
        /*
         * This would be the non-relaxed formula:
         *
         * factor = g * g / 2 / Q * (float)Math.log(2 / delta);
         *
         * The paper claims that this is more prone to oversegmenting.
         */
        factor = g * g / 2 / Q;
        logDelta = 2f * (float)Math.log(6 * w * h);

        byte[] pixel = (byte[])ip.getPixels();
        initializeRegions2D(pixel, ip.getWidth(), ip.getHeight());
        initializeNeighbors2D(pixel, w, h);
        mergeAllNeighbors2D(w);

        if (showAverages) {
            for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++)
                average[i] = average[getRegionIndex(i)];
            ip = new FloatProcessor(w, h, average, null);
        }
        else {
            int regionCount = consolidateRegions();

            if (regionCount > 1<<8) {
                if (regionCount > 1<<16)
                    IJ.showMessage("Found " + regionCount
                        + " regions, which does not fit"
                        + " in 16-bit.");
                short[] pixel16 = new short[w * h];
                for (int i = 0; i < pixel16.length; i++)
                    pixel16[i] = (short)regionIndex[i];
                ip = new ShortProcessor(w, h, pixel16, null);
            }
            else {
                pixel = new byte[w * h];
                for (int i = 0; i < pixel.length; i++)
                    pixel[i] = (byte)regionIndex[i];
                ip = new ByteProcessor(w, h, pixel, null);
            }
        }

        String title = image.getTitle() + " (SRM Q=" + Q + ")";
        return new ImagePlus(title, ip);
    }

    void initializeRegions2D(byte[] pixel, int w, int h) {
        average = new float[w * h];
        count = new int[w * h];
        regionIndex = new int[w * h];

        for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++) {
            average[i] = pixel[i] & 0xff;
            count[i] = 1;
            regionIndex[i] = i;
        }
    }

    void initializeRegions3D(int w, int h, int d) {
        average = new float[w * h * d];
        count = new int[w * h * d];
        regionIndex = new int[w * h * d];

        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            byte[] pixel =
                (byte[])image.getStack().getProcessor(j
                        + 1).getPixels();
            int offset = j * w * h;
            for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
                average[offset + i] = pixel[i] & 0xff;
                count[offset + i] = 1;
                regionIndex[offset + i] = offset + i;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void addNeighborPair(int neighborIndex,
            byte[] pixel, int i1, int i2) {
        int difference = Math.abs((pixel[i1] & 0xff)
                - (pixel[i2] & 0xff));
        nextNeighbor[neighborIndex] = neighborBucket[difference];
        neighborBucket[difference] = neighborIndex;
    }

    void initializeNeighbors2D(byte[] pixel, int w, int h) {
        nextNeighbor = new int[2 * w * h];

        // bucket sort
        neighborBucket = new int[256];
        Arrays.fill(neighborBucket, -1);

        for (int j = h - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            for (int i = w - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int index = i + w * j;
                int neighborIndex = 2 * index;

                // vertical
                if (j < h - 1)
                    addNeighborPair(neighborIndex + 1,
                        pixel, index, index + w);

                // horizontal
                if (i < w - 1)
                    addNeighborPair(neighborIndex,
                        pixel, index, index + 1);
            }
    }

    protected void addNeighborPair(int neighborIndex,
            byte[] pixel, byte[] nextPixel, int i) {
        int difference = Math.abs((pixel[i] & 0xff)
                - (nextPixel[i] & 0xff));
        nextNeighbor[neighborIndex] = neighborBucket[difference];
        neighborBucket[difference] = neighborIndex;
    }

    void initializeNeighbors3D(int w, int h, int d) {
        nextNeighbor = new int[3 * w * h * d];

        // bucket sort
        neighborBucket = new int[256];
        Arrays.fill(neighborBucket, -1);

        byte[] nextPixel = null;
        for (int k = d - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            byte[] pixel =
                (byte[])image.getStack().getProcessor(k
                        + 1).getPixels();
            for (int j = h - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                for (int i = w - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    int index = i + w * j;
                    int neighborIndex =
                        3 * (index + k * w * h);

                    // depth
                    if (nextPixel != null)
                        addNeighborPair(neighborIndex
                                + 2, pixel,
                            nextPixel, index);

                    // vertical
                    if (j < h - 1)
                        addNeighborPair(neighborIndex
                                + 1, pixel,
                            index, index + w);

                    // horizontal
                    if (i < w - 1)
                        addNeighborPair(neighborIndex,
                            pixel,
                            index, index + 1);
                }
            nextPixel = pixel;
        }
    }

    // recursively find out the region index for this pixel
    int getRegionIndex(int i) {
        i = regionIndex[i];
        while (i < 0)
            i = regionIndex[-1 - i];
        return i;
    }

    // should regions i1 and i2 be merged?
    boolean predicate(int i1, int i2) {
        float difference = average[i1] - average[i2];
        /*
         * This would be the non-relaxed predicate mentioned in the
         * paper.
         *
         * return difference * difference <
            factor * (1f / count[i1] + 1f / count[i2]);
         *
         */
        float log1 = (float)Math.log(1 + count[i1])
            * (g < count[i1] ? g : count[i1]);
        float log2 = (float)Math.log(1 + count[i2])
            * (g < count[i2] ? g : count[i2]);
        return difference * difference <
            .1f * factor * ((log1 + logDelta) / count[i1]
                + ((log2 + logDelta) / count[i2]));
    }

    void mergeAllNeighbors2D(int w) {
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborBucket.length; i++) {
            int neighborIndex = neighborBucket[i];
            while (neighborIndex >= 0) {
                int i1 = neighborIndex / 2;
                int i2 = i1
                    + (0 == (neighborIndex & 1) ? 1 : w);

                i1 = getRegionIndex(i1);
                i2 = getRegionIndex(i2);

                if (predicate(i1, i2))
                    mergeRegions(i1, i2);

                neighborIndex = nextNeighbor[neighborIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    void mergeAllNeighbors3D(int w, int h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborBucket.length; i++) {
            int neighborIndex = neighborBucket[i];
            IJ.showProgress(i, neighborBucket.length);
            while (neighborIndex >= 0) {
                int i1 = neighborIndex / 3;
                int i2 = i1
                    + (0 == (neighborIndex % 3) ? 1 :
                      (1 == (neighborIndex % 3) ? w :
                       w * h));

                i1 = getRegionIndex(i1);
                i2 = getRegionIndex(i2);

                if (i1 != i2 && predicate(i1, i2))
                    mergeRegions(i1, i2);

                neighborIndex = nextNeighbor[neighborIndex];
            }
        }
        IJ.showProgress(neighborBucket.length, neighborBucket.length);
    }

    void mergeRegions(int i1, int i2) {
        if (i1 == i2)
            return;
        int mergedCount = count[i1] + count[i2];
        float mergedAverage = (average[i1] * count[i1]
                + average[i2] * count[i2]) / mergedCount;

        // merge larger index into smaller index
        if (i1 > i2) {
            average[i2] = mergedAverage;
            count[i2] = mergedCount;
            regionIndex[i1] = -1 - i2;
        }
        else {
            average[i1] = mergedAverage;
            count[i1] = mergedCount;
            regionIndex[i2] = -1 - i1;
        }
    }

    int consolidateRegions() {
        /*
         * By construction, a negative regionIndex will always point
         * to a smaller regionIndex.
         *
         * So we can get away by iterating from small to large and
         * replacing the positive ones with running numbers, and the
         * negative ones by the ones they are pointing to (that are
         * now guaranteed to contain a non-negative index).
         */
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < regionIndex.length; i++)
            if (regionIndex[i] < 0)
                regionIndex[i] =
                    regionIndex[-1 - regionIndex[i]];
            else
                regionIndex[i] = count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you profiled your MATLAB code?

Comment: wasn't familiar with "profile" until I saw that question (I was using disp(datestrnow) before and after...profile seems way more efficient . After running profiler for srm I get calls:1, total time: 5.225s, self time: 4.899s

Comment: Well, we are not interested in the total time, but knowing wich line takes longer. can you post the result of the profiler?

Comment: This profiler thing is great, how did i not know about this!

Comment: You got 1.5 **MILLION** calls to most of the functions. Sure FIJI does that? because 5 secs for 1.5 million calls its pretty good

Comment: From what I read/understood in the nock paper, I think its inherent to the program.. the SRM compiles and sorts two lists of neighboring pixels...(image is 1571x533 pixels) 1751*533*2=1.67M.  Maybe the FIJI code has some better way of doing this? Again I'm not super familiar with Java and so can't really read through that and understand much

Comment: FiJi is developed in Java and something developers even use native (C/C++) code. Java is definitely not the fastest, but it's already a fast language, and if the native code is used then it can not be faster. However MatLab is a script language really easy to use, but one of the slowest (with R). But some MatLab functions may call a native library, so be careful to use the function that call these native libraries.